Intuition and Timescale Analysis for a Nonlinear Differential Equation Dependent on Parameter $K$
I am exploring the behavior of the following first-order nonlinear differential equation:
$$
\tau \frac{dy}{dt} = 2Ky^K(a - y^Kb)
$$
where $ y, a, b \in \mathbb{R} $, $ K \in \mathbb{N} $, and $\tau$ is a time constant.
For $ K = 1 $, there exists an analytical solution:
$$
y(t) = \frac{a}{b} \left[ \frac{e^{2at/\tau}}{e^{2at/\tau} - 1 + \frac{a/b}{y(0)}} \right]
$$
However, for general $ K $, I am doubtful about the existence of an explicit analytical solution. Can we derive some insights or intuitive understanding about:

The general behavior of $ y(t) $ as $ K $ varies?
The dependence of the system's timescale on $ K $? Is there a method or transformation that could help in understanding how quickly solutions evolve as $ K $ changes?

Any qualitative analysis, approximation techniques, or references to similar systems would be greatly appreciated.

@Moo I have not really observed any bifurcations, just global behaviors and a decrease from the line of convergence as we increase K. Would you mind sharing at which parameters you observed the bifurcation?

Before solving this problem outright, we should nondimensionalise the problem to reduce the number of parameters we need. We can set $\tau = 1$ since all solutions $y(t)$ would become $y(t/\tau)$ for other values of $\tau$. Then by rescaling all $y(t)$ by $(b/a)^{1/k},$ we can pull out these constants to reduce our equation to $$\frac{dy}{dt} = Cy^K(1-y^K),$$ where $C = \frac{2Ka^{2-1/K}}{b^{1-1/K}}.$ Differential equations of the form $$\frac{dy}{dt} = f(y)$$ are known as autonomous, and the long-time analysis is relatively straight forward.

Find all $y^*$ where $f(y^*) = 0.$ For this problem, we will have $y^* = 0, 1$ for all $K$ and $-1$ for even $K$. These are the fixed points, or constant solutions.

Compute $f'(y^*)$ for each point. If that value is negative, then it is a stable fixed point, and solutions will approach that as $t\to\infty$. If that value is positive, then it is an unstable fixed point, and solutions that are close to it will diverge from that point as $t\to\infty$. For this problem, $f'(1)$ will have the opposite sign of $C$, and $f'(-1)$ (if -1 is a fixed point) will have the same sign as $C$. $f'(0) = 0$ is where the problem actually gets interesting, in that we have to turn to a graphical analysis.

I do not have the capacity to draw the pictures, but the idea is that if you plot $f(x)$ on a graph you can draw arrows along the $x$ axis to capture the flow. If $f(x) > 0$, the arrow will point to the right, and it will point to the left when $f(x) < 0$. For example, if C = -1, K = 4, you would get something that looks like $$ -->--(-1)--<--(0)--<--(1)-->--$$ In short, solutions that start below 0 would asymptote to -1, solutions in [0,1) would asymptote to 0, and solutions greater than 1 would diverge.

All of this again describes the behavior as $t\to\infty.$ What happens in the transience is harder to describe. Technically, you can separate this problem to $$\int\frac{dy}{y^K(1-y^K)} = \int C dt,$$ but the left hand integral does not typically produce a nice function beyond the $K=1$ case you found earlier.



Let's show this with three parameter sets with $\tau = 2$ (we could fix it at one).
For $a = 3, b = 0, k = 1$, we get a single critical point at $y = 0$ and a direction field is

For $a = 3, b = 1, k = 1$, we get two critical points at $y = 0, 3$, and a direction field is

For $a = 3, b = 1, k = 2$, we get three critical points at $y = 0, \pm \sqrt{3}$ ,and a direction field is

Notice the direction of the field from the first to the third and their stability.
In general, the fixed points are given by
$$y = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 \fbox{$0\text{ if }k>0$} \\
 \fbox{$\left(\frac{a}{b}\right)^{1/k}\text{ if }(a>0\land b>0)\lor (a<0\land b<0)$} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
There is not much more than this sort of qualitative behavior regardless of the choice of parameters.
We could have nondimensionalized this as described in the other answer, but care has to be taken for the critical points in those cases.
